# How to detect if a js file is minified at run time (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, minify

I am using Node.js to minify javascript files and I would like to only minify the files that are obviously not minified already. I was wondering whether there is a way to find out if the file is minified through its content. I am using Node.js and filejs  but I am up to any method as long as it is JavaScript.

Comment: adopt a .min.js naming convention?

Comment: did the answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try by checking how long the lines are, and how many spaces are used. Minified/packed JS typically has almost no spaces (typically in strings) and very long lines.

Also, i guess you can do one more thing(which can be automated by a script), parse through both the files and check for whitespaces and compare for them in both files. Usually, the one with lesser number of whitespaces will be the minified version. Also, use the ".min.js" namming. You can also compare the size of the files between normal js file and a minified js file(which will be smaller).

Comment: You could count `\n` characters. Typically compressed javascript will have none.

Comment: Well if your going to parse the file, just add & detect  `/*I_AM_MINIFIED*/`

Comment: @AlexK. Thats a good thing to do for the future. But if he already has files which are minified right now, they wont have that tag (or comment) on top.

Answer (score 0):

Get the first , say 50 characters, and check if there is any white space characters in it. Bit hacky but will probably do